# Native library in android project not found (UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, android, linker, java-native-interface

I have an android project and I added an external .jar file which contains several *.class* files and in addition some *.so* files.

When I try to use some methods which are provided by the *.class* files I get a UnsatisfiedLinkError-Exception which says that the implementation for those methods couldn't be found.

Obviously the problem is that the *.so* libraries which contain the implementation were not correctly loaded/cannot be found.

What do I have to do that the native libraries in the external *.jar* file can be found from the runtime?

---

**More details:**

I'm using AndroidStudio and the app is tested on the emulator with the device "Nexus 5 API 23 x86". The *.so* files support x86 too.

I copied the *.jar* file into the */app/libs* folder. Then I right-clicked the file in the IDE and selected "Add as library".

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. This would include details of what CPU architectures are supported by the `.so` files, how you are including those `.so` files in your app, and what the CPU architecture is that you are testing on.

Comment: I added the information you requested. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: How are you including the `.so` files in the app? They are not in the JAR (and if they are, that's your problem). Pre-compiled `.so` files are best distributed with a JAR as part of an AAR, to avoid all of this hassle.

Comment: I don't explicitly include the *.so* files. I added a picture which shows it better i think. I did not create the *jar* myself. Should I create an AAR?

Comment: I am not aware that the approach taken by that JAR will work. I would start by contacting the developer and inquiring with them about Android support. You cannot take a random set of Linux `.so` files and expect them to work on Android, even if they are packaged in the way that the Android build tools will expect. Either the JAR developers have explicit Android support (in which case, they can tell you what to do) or they do not (in which case, this JAR probably is useless to you).

Comment: On the face of it, these so were built for x64 Linux, not for Android and not for x86

Answer (score 1):

As you see that crash is saying that it could not load native library. But why?

[image]

First of all I checked my structure, If native library .so files located correctly.

Seems everything was okay except this crazy error.

Then after some research, I find out that some of android devices has 64-bit processors.

This devices generates and check arm64 folder to load native library. 
That was the problem. Because my project does not have arm64 folder.

Here is the solution;

```
defaultConfig{
          ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
             }
         }
```